# How to format code in Angular Cli project?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, clang-format

In [Angular Cli](https://cli.angular.io/) website I found the following.

> **Test, Lint, Format**
>
> Make your code really shine. Run your unittests or your end-to-end
>   tests with the breeze of a command. Execute the  official Angular
>   linter and run clang format.

ButI did not found any command to format by angular cli.

My expectation is there could be a command or something similar to
**ng format**

Can any help me regarding this.

Note: Using clang-format by our own we can done this easily that I know. Here I am looking for angular cli command just like **ng lint**.

Comment: are you looking for `tslint --fix`?

Comment: WebStorms gives you the ability to format your code according to the linter you have added to your project. Use `ctrl-alt-l` in Linux and Windows to format your file, or, `ctrl-alt-shift-a` to format whole project

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try with the following

ng lint --format

Comment: This does not format your code.  The format flag is used to specify the format of linting errors and warnings.  Check [this documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/lint.md)